# How can I apply blur filter in Phaser 2.7

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework, pixi.js, phaserjs

Hello guys can I somebody please tell me how can I apply filters in general and specifically blur filter in Phaser 2.7?

the approach I found on chatgpt is

```
var blurYFilter = game.add.filter('BlurY');
blurYFilter.blur = 20; // Set the blur value to 20
sprite.filters = [blurYFilter];
```

but this is not working. Can you please tell me the correct way to apply filters?

I am getting this error:

c.Filter[a] is not a constructor
at c.GameObjectFactory.filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [this official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/filters/blur) for details. But basically you need to load the javascript files, that implement the blur filter for phaser ce.

```js
    game.load.script('BlurX', 'BlurX.js');
    game.load.script('BlurY', 'BlurY.js');
```

the two files you need, can be found in [the offical github repo](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-ce/tree/master/filters) here.